# $.hubConnection is undefined

Tags: signalr

I am using SignalR version 2.2.0.  With the below code, I get an exception stating that $ does not define hubConnection.  I know I have the script paths correct, because I can set breakpoints in the signalr script and see that they are hit.  I even step past where the hubConnection function is defined and still I get the exception.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        initAvailabilitySignalR("D420A92E163C43AB85CE342D5C10106B");
    });

    function initAvailabilitySignalR(tenantId) {
        try {
            var connection = $.hubConnection();

            var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('SignalRHub');

            proxy.on('AvailabilityChangedNotification', function(message) {
                try {
                    alert(message.UserId + " changed from " + message.OldAvailabilityId + " to " + message.NewAvailabilityId);
                } catch(ex) {
                    alert("Exception[On]: " + ex);
                }
            });

            connection.start().done(function() {
                try {
                    proxy.invoke("Connect", tenantId, "SOMEDOMAIN\\someuser");
                } catch(ex) {
                    alert("Exception: " + ex);
                }
            });
        } catch(ex) {
            alert("Exception: " + ex);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.  I forgot that ASP.NET MVC renders JQuery at the bottom of the page.  I moved that render statement to the top of the page and removed my explicit declaration of JQuery from the view and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also include this script tag for SignalR to work:

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: No, that's not necessary.  I don't need auto-generated proxies.  I tried it, though, and it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by my self ;), i put jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js and ~/signalr/hubs as the last js file in head section and it worked dont know what was the issue may be if put right after the jquery they load beofre jquery loads to system.